# Is it safe to assume every Android Phone has a DCIM Folder?

Tags: android

I am storing pics created from my app into DCIM folders. Is it safe to assume that DCIM folder would be present in every Android handset?

Comment: On the off-chance it doesn't, can't you create it anyways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DCIM folder is retrieved via

```
File dcimDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
    Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
```

As per the [`getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` Javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)):

> Returns the File path for the directory. **Note that this directory may not yet exist,** so you must make sure it exists before using it such as with [File.mkdirs()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()).